# zsh: permission denied: ./venv/bin; PyInstaller

Tags: python, zsh, pyinstaller

I am trying to distribute a Python script of mine using PyInstaller on MacOSX. I am trying to use PyInstaller with the packages installed on my virtual environment using Python's innate venv package.

My virtual environment directory is named venv in this instance.

I am following PyInstaller's instructions to do so, found here: https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/usage.html

However, when I run

`./venv/bin pyinstaller <SCRIPTNAME> --onefile`

The command prompt spits out this error:

`zsh: permission denied: ./venv/bin`

The only other examples of my problem occurred with users who altered their permissions prior to the problem arising, not when dealing with virtual environments, so I haven't been able to find a 
proper solution for my case.

Am I using PyInstaller with the venv incorrectly, or how do I give myself the permission needed to run the correct command?

Comment: `./venv/bin` isn't a command name; it's the directory where your virtual environment's executables are stored. I suspect you installed Pyinstaller in your virtual environment, in which case you just want `./venv/bin/pyinstaller <SCRIPTNAME> --onefile`.

Comment: `pyinstaller <SCRIPTNAME> --onefile` would also work, as activating a virtual environment adds its `bin` directory to the front of your `PATH`.

Comment: @chepner that doesn't work as such syntax makes terminal read ".../pyinstaller" as some sort of directory location when it isn't; I did try that however prior, and it didn't work for that reason. I believe the second comment of yours does work as you said. I used Jorge's answer below, but there's more than one way to skin a cat! Thanks to you for your insight.

Comment: `./venv/bin/pystaller` is just a path; it might refer to a file or a directory. If it's not a path to your `pystaller` executable, then obviously it's not the right path to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm where you able to do

```
 source bin/activate
```

This is required in order to add that source into the permissions lists as +x in your venv.

For more information please refer to [1]

Hope this helps

---

[1] https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/

Comment: Yes, I was able to do this, however I couldn't use the command in the OP when working in the venv.

Comment: Update: I'm not sure what exactly changed, but this solution is now working. Maybe I just had to turn it off and back on again.